# Check/uncheck radios

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Made this script

```
function Resetradio() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName("tjek");

var i = 0;
while (i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) 
    selectedradio = i;
    i++;
}
var i = 0;
while (i < radios.length) {
    if (!selectedradio == i) 
    radios.checked = false
    i++;
}
}
<form name="Form1" action="" method="get">
    <input name="tjek" type="radio" value="" onclick="Resetradio()" />
    <input name="tjek" type="radio" value="" onclick="Resetradio()" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<form name="Form2" action="" method="get">
    <input name="tjek" type="radio" value="" onclick="Resetradio()" />
    <input name="tjek" type="radio" value="" onclick="Resetradio()" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhP3K/

which should run through all radios and collect the one selected and then run through them again to unselect all others if there are any other selected. Where is the fault?

Comment: try defining selectedradio beforehand.

var selectedradio;

or

var selectedradio = i;

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: try making a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can have multiple buttons selected. So `selectedradio` will always be the highest index of the selected buttons. If you try to select a button with a lower index it will be "reset" immediately in your second loop. Think about it:

- Button 3 gets selected `->` `selectedradio === 3`
- Button 0, 1 and 2 are reset
- Button 1 gets selected `->` `selectedradio === 3`, since `radios[3].checked` is still `true`.
- Button 0, 1 and 2 are reset

So, instead of iterating over the buttons to find out which one was selected, simply pass the a reference of the selected button to the function:

```
function Resetradio(selected) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("tjek");

    var i = 0;
    while (i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i] !== selected) 
        radios[i].checked = false
        i++;
    }
}
```

to be called with

```
onchange="Resetradio(this)"
```